# "Streaking" in SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

So I have a very simple jobs table, with the following columns:

```
completed_at
user_id
type_id
status_id
```

Each job is manually approved or rejected, assigning it a status_id of 1 or 2 respectively.

I'd like to query the database, based on this format of rule:

```
minimum_streak:               X
 (number of sequential jobs with the same type_id with status_id = 1)

automatic_approval_frequency: Y 
 (every 5th job, after the minimum_streak, is automatically approved)
```

I'd like to return the jobs that would have been automatically approved, had that rule been implemented.

My attempts so far have all had iterative issues which I'd rather avoid, as 'pretending' a previously rejected job was instead approved causes the streaks to change.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/27551

FWIW, I'm working with RoR & Postgres.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sample data would help, ideally in a SQLFiddle

Comment: Here you go David, I'll add it to the original question too:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/27551

Comment: Haven't got time to work things out very far, but have a play around with http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/27551/7, which identifies rows based on the number of immediately prior rows with the same status_id

Comment: If minumum streak is an increasing number how can aproval be after it?And have you look at solutions to similar problems?

Comment: That looks fantastic David, thanks. Getting acquainted pretty quickly with a whole load of new PG functions there!

I'm worried that this approach still doesn't accurately represent what would have happened. i.e. if a user had a streak of 5, and failed number 6, but the rule would have passed it, number 7 should continue in the same (now virtual, I guess) streak.